# Is a payments callback URL required with Facebook local currency flow?

Tags: facebook, payment

While implementing and testing local currency payment flow for my app I got an error with the pay dialog.

```
error_code = 1383044
error_message = "no callback url"
```

I have been reading the How-To at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/ and the impression I got was that the payments callback was optional.  However this error message seems to imply that it is required.  Is setting up a payments callback a must for local currency payments?

(also, as a side question, are real time updates different from the payments callback? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/fulfillment/#rtu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the payments callback URL is not required, as long as you are using **static pricing**.  Dynamic pricing does require the payments callback.

It turns out that I had a bug in my Open Graph object template that caused Facebook's Open Graph parser to not recognize the price data for the product I was testing.  Since there was no price data, Facebook treated the item as a dynamically priced item. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/definingproducts/#pricing_dynamic)

Comment: Hi amacleod, i experience the same issue, my server is not involve in the process so i really don't know if the user bought coins cause the payment callback url is not being called now, i tried to use real time update to get facebook data but can make it work, what is the best practice to involve the server in the process so it will be aware of the purchase?

Comment: I followed the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ and added the callback using the App Dashboard page. Hope that helps!